# Amplify: dynamically sharing S3 files between Cognito users

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, graphql, aws-amplify

I have an amplify react app which allows users to upload **private** files and view them. I would like to implement a feature in which the uploader can dynamically specify who else (which users) can also view & modify these files. However, these files would remain private to only the uploader and the shared with users, no one else.

My app is setup with:

- storage: S3
- auth: Cognito
- db: DynamoDB
- api: graphQL

The app stores private files on the S3 bucket:

```
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';
const response = await Storage.put(file.name, file, { level: 'private', progress(progress) {...} });
```

The returned file path from `response.key` is stored in the database using the graphQL api based of this schema:

```
type File @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
    id: ID!
    s3Key: String
}
```

When presenting the data & files to the uploader, I query this schema to display the files relevant to the specific user only and fetch them using:

```
url = await Storage.get(response.key, {level: 'private'})
```

This is because the Cognito identity of that user is used in the S3 policy (somewhere?) to establish access.

Now, I would like to implement file sharing between some users. It was quite easy to do it on the database level with this modification to the schema:

```
type File @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }, { allow: owner, ownerField: "owners" }]) {
    id: ID!
    s3Key: String
    owners: [String]
}
```

So now the uploader can specify users who will be able to fetch this data out of the db by simply adding usernames to the array in the `owners` field.

However, I am not sure how I can make the files stored on the S3 bucket available to the other owners.

I cannot use owner's key because the stored files are only available to the uploader (as they should) and I am not sure how the code could specify the different Cognito identities that can access/modify a particular file. I need to find a way to grant access.

Just to clarify: the uploader of the file lists who specifically (cognito identity / username) can access the file. They can add and remove on the go the accounts with the access to the file (so this is basically a modification to the `owners` field in the database).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never tried anything like this, however one solution probably would be lambda via API gateway that takes URL other people requested and creates a signed URL with an expiration of several seconds.. And get that URL on client instead.